# how to release a project under the AGPL

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

We are developing an enrollment system through asp.net (c#), we are required to generate PDF reports and be deployed on a Web Host. We are going to use iTextSharp since it can be used for free but under Affero General Public License (AGPL). How can we deploy oursystem that is under Affero General Public License (AGPL) or more likely the free versions of iTextSharp ?

Comment: [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)

Answer (score 2):

You need to distribute the complete source code of the project using iTextSharp using the same medium you use to distribute your software. For instance: in old days, software was distributed on a CD. In that case, the complete source code had to be distributed on the same CD(-set).

In your case, you are distributing the code on a Web Host (the main difference between the AGPL and the GPL is that putting code on a web site is also considered as distribution). This means that you should host the complete source code on the same site where you deploy your application.

Everybody visiting your site needs to have access to your complete source code. As many companies wish to avoid this, they purchase a commercial license.

There is also a persistent misconception where some project manager think *"we did not modify iText, hence we do not have the obligation to share our code."* That is wrong: linking to an AGPL library is generally considered being a modification of the library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, should all of our source code be downloadable or the codes only that have iText within it?

Comment: The complete project that uses iText should be released under the AGPL. For instance: you have one module that uses iText. That module should be AGPL. Then you have a larger project that uses that AGPL module. That project should also be released under the AGPL. And so on...